# ¿Como hacer mix de MVC Razor y javascript cuando hay " } "?

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo una lista de objetos que los envío a la vista para mostrar imágenes como un libro, entonces hago una mezcla de *razor* con *javascript*, pero me da un error por las llaves `}`.

Código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".book1").flipBook({
             lightBox: true,
             pages: [
                    @{
                     int cantidad =0;
                     int limite=Convert.ToInt32(@ViewBag.cantidad);
                     foreach(var item in @ViewBag.lista){

                             <text>
                             { este es para crear el objeto en javascript
                                 src: "@Url.Content("~/prueba/"+item.Cod_insti+"/"+item.Cod_materia+"_"+item.Cod_nivel+"_"+item.Cod_seccion+"/album/"+item.Imagen)",
                                 thumb: "@Url.Content("~/prueba/"+item.Cod_insti+"/"+item.Cod_materia+"_"+item.Cod_nivel+"_"+item.Cod_seccion+"/album/"+item.Imagen)",
                                 title: @item.Nombre_materia
                             
                        </text>
                        cantidad++;
                       if(cantidad == limite)

                        <text>}</text>cierre de lista de objetos en javascript

                       else

                      <text>},</text> aqui es donde tengo el problema con } porque ese es para cerrar el objeto y crear otro pero  me  cierra flipBook({

                     }

                          }

             ]
         });-->aqui no me lo reconoce porque arriba pongo } entonces cierra

     }) -->aqui no me lo reconoce porque arriba pongo } entonces cierra
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

gracias a todos ya lo resolvi lo deje asi para alguien que lo ocupe

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

         $(".book1").flipBook({
             lightBox: true,
             pages: [
             @foreach(var item in @ViewBag.lista){
                 int limite=Convert.ToInt32(@ViewBag.cantidad);
                 if (item.Indice < limite){
                 <text>
            
                 {
                    
                     src: "@Url.Content("~/prueba/"+item.Cod_insti+"/"+item.Cod_materia+"_"+item.Cod_nivel+"_"+item.Cod_seccion+"/album/"+item.Imagen)",
                     thumb: "@Url.Content("~/prueba/"+item.Cod_insti+"/"+item.Cod_materia+"_"+item.Cod_nivel+"_"+item.Cod_seccion+"/album/"+item.Imagen)",
                     title: "@item.Indice"
                 },
                     </text>
                
             }else{
                   <text>
            
                 {
                    
                     src: "@Url.Content("~/prueba/"+item.Cod_insti+"/"+item.Cod_materia+"_"+item.Cod_nivel+"_"+item.Cod_seccion+"/album/"+item.Imagen)",
                     thumb: "@Url.Content("~/prueba/"+item.Cod_insti+"/"+item.Cod_materia+"_"+item.Cod_nivel+"_"+item.Cod_seccion+"/album/"+item.Imagen)",
                     title: "@item.Nombre_materia"
                 }
                     </text>
                 
                 
                 }
                 
                 
             }
                       
                
             
       
             ]
         });//book1
     })//read
```